# JavaScript - Stop Bubbling

Tags: javascript, html

I wondered if someone could take a look at the following JS I need help on? What I want to happen is to be able to click the `div` and the alert box "Here" appear, which it does. I also want to be able to click the `a` and have the "Anchor" alert appear, which it does.

The problem is that the "Here" alert box then appears again. I've tried using `.stopPropagation()` but is not working as expected.

My code:

```js
function testMessage() {
  alert("Here");
}

function anchorClick() {
  alert("Anchor");
  this.stopPropagation();
}

var products = document.getElementsByClassName('Wrapper')
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].onclick = function() {
    testMessage();
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
  tags[i].onclick = function() {
    anchorClick();
  }
}
```

```css
#Wrapper,
#Wrapper2 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link1</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link2</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link3</a>
</div>

<div class="Wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link1</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link2</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link3</a>
</div>
```

Please can you advise?

Cheers
Chris

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qk0bceup/5/

Comment: Post your code *here*, not on some 3rd party site.

Comment: Ok, will note this in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the `event` to your function, you are using `this` which refers to `window`.

```js
function testMessage() {
  alert("Here");
}

function anchorClick(e) {
  alert("Anchor");
  e.stopPropagation();
}

var products = document.getElementsByClassName('Wrapper')
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].onclick = function() {
    testMessage();
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
  tags[i].onclick = function(e) {
    anchorClick(e);
  }
}
```

```css
#Wrapper,
#Wrapper2 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link1</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link2</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link3</a>
</div>

<div class="Wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link1</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link2</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link3</a>
</div>
```

BTW, it's not necessary to declare a function to call your event function, if you have this:

```
products[i].onclick = function() {
    testMessage();
}
```

You can assign your `testMessage` function directly:

```
products[i].onclick = testMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the browser console, you'll find the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.stopPropagation is not a function

As you can see, `this` is not the object your're looking for but it's the `window` reference.

`stopPropagation()` is a method of the `event` object, [see documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

See example:

```js
function testMessage() {
  console.log("Here");
}

function anchorClick() {
  console.log("'this' references to window: " + this);
  console.log("Anchor");
  event.stopPropagation();
}

var products = document.getElementsByClassName('Wrapper')
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].onclick = function() {
    testMessage();
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
  tags[i].onclick = function() {
    anchorClick();
  }
}
```

```css
#Wrapper,
#Wrapper2 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link1</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link2</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link3</a>
</div>

<div class="Wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link1</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link2</a>
  <a href="#" class="anchor">Link3</a>
</div>
```